# Alfresco Rest API to get the current node version

Tags: api, rest, version, alfresco

I'm making a call to `GET service/api/version?nodeRef={nodeRef}`, but I want to limit the query to just the most recent version.  I found this StackOverflow post which suggests the use of `&filter={filterQuery?}` to filter results, but that looks like it only applies to the people query method.  Is there something like this for the version method?

Comment: What are you trying to get? There may be a better API to call

Comment: I'm just trying to get the node ID of the most recent version.  I don't need all of the historical versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your specific query, a general point. Alfresco community is open source, and almost all of Alfresco Enterprise is too, so for many queries around this your best bet is simply to go and check the source code yourself! The rest APIs are held in the [projects/remote-api](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/)

Looking in there, you can see that the [versions webscript](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates//webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/version/version.get.js) returns all versions for a given node. It's fairly fast to do that, so calling that and getting the most recent one isn't the end of the world

Otherwise, the [slingshot node details api](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/node.get.desc.xml) at `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib2/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}` (add the parts of the noderef into the URL) will return lots of information on a node quickly, including the latest version. In the JSON returned by that, inside the item key is something like

```
"version": "1.7",
```

Which gives you the latest version for the node

Some of the listing and search APIs will also include the version, but those are likely to be quite a bit more heavyweight than just getting the version history of a node

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions.  I read somewhere else that it was suggested never to use the slingshot API's since they aren't considered "public" API's, but supposed to be internal-only Alfresco API's. I'm definitely starting to see the value of looking at the code for some of this stuff.  In my opinion, documentation for much of this stuff  is terrible, so I'm going to the source more and more often.  Thanks.  I'll mark this as answer even though I may not use the slingshot api unless you think it's safe to use the internal API's (won't change next release)

Comment: CMIS is very well documented, and very well supported, so the official answer across all versions is to use CMIS